# DRY - Stopping repetitition in MVC actions Get, Edit and Delete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dry

Suppose I have a CategoriesController for managing some kind of categories list. It has these action methods:

```
public ActionResult Get(Int32 categoryId);

public ActionResult Edit(Int32 categoryId);

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Int32 categoryId, CategoryModel model);

public ActionResult Delete(Int32 categoryId);

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(Int32 categoryId, DeleteModel model);
```

All of these methods run the same code that verifies that `categoryId` is valid and the category exists, it retrieves it from the database, and performs access-level verification. Parts of the verification code returns an ActionResult directly, others do not (for example, if the categoryId doesn't exist, then it will return a Http404 action result immediately, but if everything's okay then it goes down to the action-specific code.

Is the best way to cut down on code duplication to do something like this?

```
private ActionResult EnsureCategory(Int32 categoryId, out DBCategory dbCategory);

public ActionResult Edit(Int32 categoryId) {
    DBCategory dbCategory;
    ActionResult error = EnsureCategory(categoryId, out dbCategory);
    if( error != null ) return error;

    // this now means that only 3 lines of code will be shared between the Action methods, but it still seems too much.
}
```

It's a shame C# doesn't support preprocessor macros, or something like it, because this would be a good place to use them. Unless there's a better approach?

Comment: Preprocessors macro can be replaced by T4 templates. This can even go far beyond simple preprocessor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up continuing to use the approach I suggested to myself in my original question. I did consider using @SteveB's T4 template suggestion, but I find T4 templates a bit hard to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use [action filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs), do your validation inside `OnActionExecuting` method.

Comment: The problem with filters is that it's hard to pass objects and state from the filter to the action method (such as a DB connection or an object returned from the DB during a verification check).

Comment: @David If you need to check whether object does exist in database, you can simply throw exception and then return specific error via error handling filter.

Comment: @David Mostly you don't pass object and state from filter to action. Db connection should be provided by factory or DI, and verification checks should not return objects from Db. If you still need to do that, you can do it via normal model-binding (and argument naming convention) or custom action invoker.